# Creating Angularjs directive instead of jQuery heavy function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have the following javascript function made mostly from jquery that I run as soon as the page loads. I am trying to turn this into an angularjs directive but I'm having trouble figuring out how to accomplish it.

I'm new to angular so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The only *not known* variable is `PDFWIDTH` but I will have that in a `$scope.pdf_width` variable when the template loads.

**JQUERY FUNCTION**

```
function zoomProject() { 

    var maxWidth = $("#formBox").width(), percent = maxWidth / PDFWIDTH;

    $("#formScale").css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
        '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
        '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')'
    });
    $(".trimSpace").css('width', (PDFWIDTH * percent) + 'px');
    $("#formBox, .trimSpace").css('height', ($("#formScale").height() * percent) + 'px');

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="formBox">
    <div class="trimSpace">
        <div id="formScale"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I have the basis down to make resize an element to fit the entire window width and height. I'm trying to figure out the most appropriate way to do it.

What do you guys think? Just copy the jquery stuff I have above and make it sort of like how the below directive works? Or do you think there is a better javascript/angular way of doing it?

```
.directive('zoom', function ($window) {
    return function (scope, element) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        scope.getWindowDimensions = function () { return { 'h': w.height(), 'w': w.width() }; };
        scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
            scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
            scope.style = function (amount) { return {  'height': (newValue.h - amount) + 'px', 'width': (newValue.w - amount) + 'px' }; };
        }, true);
        w.bind('resize', function () { scope.$apply(); });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question. If anyone has any suggestions please don't hesitate.

Here it is if anyone is interested:

**JS**

```
.directive('zoom', function ($window) {
        return function (scope, element) {
            var w = angular.element($window);
            scope.getWindowDimensions = function () { return { 'h': w.height(), 'w': w.width() }; };
            scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
                scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
                var formBox = angular.element($("#formBox")), formScale = angular.element($("#formScale"));
                scope.formScale = function(pdfwidth) { 
                    var percent = formBox.width() / pdfwidth;
                    return { 'width': pdfwidth+'px', 'transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')', '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')', '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')', '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')' } 
                };

                scope.trimSpace = function(pdfwidth) {
                    var percent = formBox.width() / pdfwidth;
                    return { 'width': (pdfwidth * percent)+'px', 'height': (formScale.height() * percent)+'px'  } 
                };

                scope.formBox = function(pdfwidth) {
                    var percent = formBox.width() / pdfwidth;
                    return { 'height': (formScale.height() * percent)+'px'  } 
                }

            }, true);
            w.bind('resize', function () { scope.$apply(); });
        }
    })
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="formBox" ng-style="formBox(pdf_width)" zoom>
    <div class="trimSpace" ng-style="trimSpace(pdf_width)" zoom>
        <div id="formScale" ng-style="formScale(pdf_width)" zoom></div>
    </div>
</div>
```